# How to add Recently opened files item to xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin right pane?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, menu, whisker

In xfce4-whiskermenu the right pane has an item **Recently Used**, it is for apps/programs. I'd like to know if is possible to add an item to show **Recently Opened Files** to the right pane of xfce4-whiskermenu. OS: Xubuntu 16.04.6

thanks, vladi

Comment: I am not sure if you can add the Recently Opened Files to the whisker menu.  I don't see anything that comes with it by default to add that.  It would probably have to be added by changing the source code.  But, if you add the `Places` item to the panel, that by default has a Recent Documents at the bottom of it.

Comment: @Terrance Ok, Places added and there is a option "Recents Documents", thanks ,this is a pit I can't add to whiskermenu.

Answer (score 0):

As there isn't a "recent files" feature within the Whisker-menu, we have to look for workarounds:

- Search actions can be added for files and folders by adding Catfish to "Search actions", which is a very useful but not very well known feature of Whisker menu, details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/785894/925128).
- Use Synapse launcher to open files, especially recent ones. Just opening Synapse and clicking DOWN-ARROW shows recently opened files (those that have been already accessed through the file manager). For more details look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546708/341192) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1180249/925128).